# Modifying pandas dataframe through function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, pandas, dataframe

I tried to modify the dataframe through function and return the modified dataframe.  Somehow, it is not reflected.  In the below code, I pass a dataframe 'ding' to function 'test' and create a new column 'C' and return the modified dataframe.  I expected the test_ding df to have 3 columns but could see only two columns.  Any help is highly appreciated.

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,3,5,6,8,10,1,1,1,1,1,1])
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,6,8,10,1,7,1,6,5,4,3])

ding=pd.DataFrame({'A':s1,'B':s2})

def test(ding):
    ding.C=ding.A+ding.B
    return ding

test_ding=test(ding)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ding.C doesn't exist and can't be accessed like an attribute. 
You need to change the line to

```
ding['C']=ding.A+ding.B
```

You can create an column like `ding['A'] = blah` which then turns into an attribute of the DataFrame.  But you can't go the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,3,5,6,8,10,1,1,1,1,1,1])
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,6,8,10,1,7,1,6,5,4,3])

ding=pd.DataFrame({'A':s1,'B':s2})

def test(ding):
    ding = ding.assign(C=ding.A+ding.B)
    return ding

test_ding=test(ding)

print(test_ding)
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C
0    1   4   5
1    3   5   8
2    5   6  11
3    6   8  14
4    8  10  18
5   10   1  11
6    1   7   8
7    1   1   2
8    1   6   7
9    1   5   6
10   1   4   5
11   1   3   4
```